# wp_editor returns the shortcode and not render the output

Tags: shortcode

I built a plugin, and I would like to use shortcodes in the integrated wp_editor.

I'm using echo to display the content of the wp_editor, so I think that's the problem why I can't use the shortcode. What's the method to do that?

I'm using the following code for shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('facebook', 'facebook');

function facebook($atts) {
    $options = get_option( 'social_options' );
    return '<a class="socialmedia socialfacebook" href="'.$options["facebook"].'">Facebook</a>';
}
```

..and the following code to get the content of the wp_editor:

```
<?php
    $footer = get_option('footer_options');
    $footer_content = array($footer['footer_content_1'], $footer['footer_content_2']);
    foreach($footer_content as $content) {
        echo'<aside class="tab-content">
            '.$content.'
        </aside>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try doing this

```
 <?php
$footer = get_option('footer_options');
$footer_content = array($footer['footer_content_1'], $footer['footer_content_2']);
foreach($footer_content as $content) {
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    echo'<aside class="tab-content">
        '.$content.'
    </aside>';
}
 ?>
```

I once had the same issue and applying the content filter solved it